# Delphi 2010: unable to find resource - EResNotFound

Tags: delphi, resources

Based on examples at for instance [here](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2606.asp?SK=), [here](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-pascal-delphi-misc/135237-including-string-ascii-file-compile-time.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087402/delphi-pre-build-event-not-executing-before-compile), I'm trying to include SVN revision info in a project. The result of a svn info call is stored in `rev.txt` (it's a plain ansi file). My `revinfo.rc` looks like this:

```
REV_TEXT    TEXT    rev.txt
```

My project looks like this:

```
unit rev;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;
var
  Form2: TForm2;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
{$R revinfo.res}
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RS : TResourceStream;
  MyStr : AnsiString;
begin
  RS := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'REV_TEXT', RT_RCDATA);
  SetLength(MyStr, RS.Size);
  RS.Read(MyStr[1], RS.Size);
  RS.Free;
  Memo1.Text := MyStr;
end;
end.
```

The project compiles, in other words, the resource file itself is located by the compiler (or perphaps it is the linker?). Anyway; when the statement `TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'REV_TEXT', RT_RCDATA);` is executed, I get an EResNotFound exception, complaining it can't find resource REV_TEXT. I can confirm that the resource file is compiled satisfactory, containing the content of the `rev.txt` text file. Are there anyone out there who're able to reproduce my troubles?

BTW: I've also tried to use the indexed version of the TResourceStream-constructor, but I don't know which index to use (tried 0, 1, and 2 to no avail).

I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is the line:

```
 TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'REV_TEXT', RT_RCDATA);
```

You must call the `TResourceStream.Create` with the same type of the resource `TEXT`.

The following code should work:

```
var
  RS : TResourceStream;
  MyStr : AnsiString;
begin
  RS := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'REV_TEXT', 'TEXT');
  try
   SetLength(MyStr, RS.Size);
   RS.Read(MyStr[1], RS.Size);
  finally
    RS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. (Although the text comes out in Chinese ... oh, well. One step further, at least.) :)

Comment: Figured it out. The string type obviously have to be AnsiString as shown in RRUZ answer (the file is, as mentioned, a Ansi encoded file). I've changed the MyStr in the original question to not lead people astray.