# Loading Bitmap From Resource

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I find a solution for Loading Bitmap From Resource file on [How to store images in FireMonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426914/how-to-store-images-in-firemonkey) And I've tried to use it in my Firemonkey application, but it can't find Resource and raises an error "EresNotFound".
My Resource .RC File Is Like This

```
Bitmap_1    BITMAP    "Test.bmp"
```

and my Code is

```
procedure Tform1.load_image_from_resource(var Im1: Timage; res_name: String);
var InStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  InStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, res_name,RC_RTDATA);
  try
    Im1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(InStream);
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Load_image_from_resource(Image1,'Bitmap_1');
end;
```

I also found a solution on the question [Delphi 2010: unable to find resource - EResNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663303/delphi-2010-unable-to-find-resource-eresnotfound).
But it still doesn't find recource

Comment: Have you read this article https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/surviving-without-image-lists-in-fmx/ and followed all the steps from there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, you need to declare resource as RCDATA

```
Bitmap_1    RCDATA    "Test.bmp"
```

Also looks like you created VCL application and there is a typo in resource type name, it should be RT_RCDATA, working FireMonkey code looks like this

```
procedure Tform1.load_image_from_resource(var Im1: Timage; res_name: String);
var InStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  InStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, res_name, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Im1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(InStream);
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Load_image_from_resource(Image1, 'Bitmap_1');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It work's properly.  thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fayyaz, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it is the solution to your problem...

Comment: `BITMAP` is a valid [resource type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009.aspx), you can use `RT_BITMAP` instead of `RT_RCDATA` when creating the `TResourceStream`.