# Query Git Data during compile and build of a delphi app

Tags: git, delphi

We are using GIT as a  source code repository for our Delphi projects.

Can I get Git Branch ID , Git Revision number, ....  each time I compile my apps?

I would like  to show  these  data  in some  help box

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087402/delphi-pre-build-event-not-executing-before-compile) can be useful.

Comment: Note that those who *wrote* Git set up their builds to capture version information by running `git describe`. Doesn't mean that's the right answer, but, well, Linus and Junio do kind of know what they're doing with Git. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here the answers:

- *Git branch id* by `git branch --show-current`
- *Git revision number* by `git rev-parse HEAD` (NB: the revision number is the last commit hash)